# How to Automatically Run Script on AWS EC2 Instance Startup?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vps

I would like to create a Python script and run it on an AWS EC2 instance (t3.micro with Windows). I want the script to start automatically when I turn on the instance. Do you think if I set it to start when the PC boots up, it would start when I start the instance from the AWS control panel or when I connect via RDP???

And if it's the second option, is there a way to start it without having to connect via RDP?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instances can run scripts at the initial launch (or at every reboot if set up).

You have to include these scripts in the EC2 user data.

Please refer to the user data on AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)

To set the execution (initial launch, reboot, restart) please check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html#user-data-execution) out.